# Are the Voyager spacecraft outside of our Solar System?

Tags: solar-system, oort-cloud

The wikipedia says that Voyager 1 cross the heliosphere, but is really outside the Solar System, or need to cross the Oort cloud?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "solar system", and what is meant by the "edge of the solar system".